# Running mongo shell script using kubernetes job

Tags: mongodb, shell, kubernetes, jobs

I need to create kubernetes job that will run below script on mongo shell:

```
var operations = [];
db.product.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var documentLink = doc.documentLink; 
    var operation = { updateMany :{ 
"filter" : {"_id" : doc._id},
"update" : {$set:{"documentLinkMap.en":documentLink,"documentLinkMap.de":""},
    $unset: {documentLink:"","descriptionMap.tr":"","news.tr":"","descriptionInternal.tr":"","salesDescription.tr":"","salesInternal.tr":"","deliveryDescription.tr":"","deliveryInternal.tr":"","productRoadMapDescription.tr":"","productRoadMapInternal.tr":"","technicalsAndIntegration.tr":"","technicalsAndIntegrationInternal.tr":"","versions.$[].descriptionMap.tr":"","versions.$[].releaseNoteMap.tr":"","versions.$[].artifacts.$[].descriptionMap.tr":"","versions.$[].artifacts.$[].artifactNotes.tr":""}}}};
    operations.push(operation); 
});
operations.push( {
    ordered: true,      
    writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000 } 
});
db.product.bulkWrite(operations);
```

I will need a sample of how that job will look like. Should I create presistent volume and claim to it or is there possibility to run this job without persistent volume? I need to run this once and then remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it much easier with [`configMap`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) and then mount the `configMap` as a volume which will be resolved in a file.

Below is example how to proceed with it (Note! You will need to use a proper image for it as well as some other changes how mongo shell works):

1. Create a `configMap` from file. Can be done by running this command:

   ```
   $ kubectl create cm mongoscript-cm --from-file=mongoscript.js
   configmap/mongoscript-cm created
   ```

   You can check that you file is stored inside by running:

   ```
   $ kubectl describe cm mongoscript-cm
   ```
2. Create a job with volume mount from configmap ([spec template is the same as it used in pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#pod-template)):

   ```
   apiVersion: batch/v1
   kind: Job
   metadata:
     name: mongojob
   spec:
     template:
       spec:
         containers:
         - name: mongojob
           image: ubuntu # for testing purposes, you need to use appropriate one
           command: ['bin/bash', '-c', 'echo STARTED ; cat /opt/mongoscript.js ; sleep 120 ; echo FINISHED'] # same for command, that's for demo purposes
           volumeMounts:
           - name: mongoscript
             mountPath: /opt # where to mount the file
         volumes:
         - name: mongoscript
           configMap:
             name: mongoscript-cm # reference to previously created configmap
         restartPolicy: OnFailure # required for jobs
   ```
3. Checking how it looks inside the pod

   Connect to the pod:

   ```
   $ kubectl exec -it mongojob--1-8w4ml -- /bin/bash
   ```

   Check file is presented:

   ```
   # ls /opt
   mongoscript.js
   ```

   Check its content:

   ```
   # cat /opt/mongoscript.js 
   var operations = [];
   db.product.find().forEach(function(doc) {
       var documentLink = doc.documentLink; 
       var operation = { updateMany :{ 
   "filter" : {"_id" : doc._id},
   "update" : {$set {"documentLinkMap.en":documentLink,"documentLinkMap.de":""},
       $unset: {documentLink:"","descriptionMap.tr":"","news.tr":"","descriptionInternal.tr":"","salesDescription.tr":"","salesInternal.tr":"","deliveryDescription.tr":"","deliveryInternal.tr":"","productRoadMapDescription.tr":"","productRoadMapInternal.tr":"","technicalsAndIntegration.tr":"","technicalsAndIntegrationInternal.tr":"","versions.$[].descriptionMap.tr":"","versions.$[].releaseNoteMap.tr":"","versions.$[].artifacts.$[].descriptionMap.tr":"","versions.$[].artifacts.$[].artifactNotes.tr":""}}}};
       operations.push(operation); 
   });
   operations.push( {
       ordered: true,      
       writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000 } 
   });
   db.product.bulkWrite(operations);
   ```